# Detecting modifications to an unknown template object

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I'm currently working on three custom containers of pointers, and am interested in detecting when the state of the base-most pointer changes.

The first container (Host) is a class with a unique pointer to an object provided by a template, as well as a list of registered Observers. When it's destroyed or the template's data is modified, it will tell each of the observers that the event happened.

The second container (Observer) is a class that holds a pointer to a Host and two lambda functions that are called when either the host's template data is modified (doModified), or the host is deleted (doDeleted). It registers itself when it is assigned a host.

The third container (ObserverVector) is a vector that holds observers that may or may not be registered to different hosts. It inserts it's own functions into the Observers' lambda functions, so that it can purge when hosts are deleted, as well as do self maintenance when hosts are modified.

Implementing doDeleted was simple enough, but I am stumped on implementing doModified. What I initially wanted was to find out when the template's assignment operator was called, but this would not be a good fit for any object that could be modified through functions that are not default operators. My current best solution is to only use the container with classes that I've defined with an IsModified lambda member, call that member in every modifying function, and have the Host insert one of it's functions into that member. This is going to be a chore if I'm using this throughout my codebase though.

My primary reason for not using regular weak pointers in the ObserverVector is performance concerns: I'd be reading through every ObserverVector's entire container potentially (and unavoidably) multiple times for every tick in my game. I know I'm dealing with an inherently O(n*log(n)) problem, so cutting down on validity checks would help me on that front. Implementing a form of iterative garbage collection that sweeps at the end of a game tick is my end goal: I want to hide vector resize and reordering thrashing during excess time before the next game tick.

Long story short: I want to know if there's a less verbose and less intrusive solution to figuring out when the contained data is modified, while still keeping it generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I don't think there's a better solution than the one you proposed. You may be able to cut down on boilerplate code by defining a base class to handle attaching and calling `doModified` callbacks though. Then you'd just need to inherit from that class and add one function call per mutator.

For example,

```
class Modifiable
{
public:
    addObserver(Observer& observer) { /*...*/ }
protected:
    isModified() { /* Invoke callbacks */ }
private:
    // Member(s) to manage callback list
}

class Foo : public Modifiable
{
public:
    void set_value(/*...*/)
    {
        // Change some member data...
        isModified();
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you want your `Host`s to be able to store types you didn't write, you'll have to write a wrapper class for each such type.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if creating a Manager Class that is a singleton wrapper around your hosts and observers that has a member function that accepts your 3rd container as input. This way your manager class that encapsulates your Hosts & Observers does all of the checking for your while your classes does only the work they need to. So if a Host is deleted it will report back to the Manager Class and the Manager Class will take that report and disperse it to all of the contained Observers or your Vector of Observers. Another words this Manager Class will do all of the processing that checks for changes in behavior and book keeping while leaving the contained classes to do only the work they need to.